# MS-Excel copy specific cells in new worksheet after filtreing data

Tags: excel, filter, worksheet, vba

I have worksheet "Recalculated FS" with columns : A, B, C, D, E ..AI
I want to filter my worksheet if AI = "YES" then copy columns B and D in new worksheet "Sheet2", I have this code who copy all the columns and I don't know how to do it work for column B and D,
Ps : I want also to rename the header of "Sheet2" , B -- > columnB and C--> columnC

```
Sub tgr()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsData = Sheets("Recalculated FS")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")

With wsData.Range("AI2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp))
    .AutoFilter 1, "YES"
 .CurrentRegion.Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
    .AutoFilter

End With
End Sub
```

Help please ?
Now I need to add to filter 1 (AI column), another filter 2 (column AK) , so how can I do it in this code :

```
Option Explicit
Sub tgr()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsData = Sheets("Recalculated FS")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")

' set wsData sheet to be active, to allow filterring
 wsData.Select
 With wsData.Range("AI2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp))
' Column AI is col num 35
.AutoFilter 35, "YES"
 End With

wsData.Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy

wsDest.Select
Columns("B:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsData.Select
wsData.Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Copy

wsDest.Select
Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsDest.Range("B1").Value = "ColumnB"
wsDest.Range("D1").Value = "ColumnD"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below copies **Column B** and **Column D** to worksheet **Sheet2**, when Column AI = Yes.

**Edit 1**: copies **Column B** and **Column D** one by one to *Sheet 2* (without copying Column C)

**Edit 2**: added second Filter criteria of Column AK = Yes

```
Option Explicit

Sub tgr()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Set wsData = Sheets("Recalculated FS")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet2")

' set wsData sheet to be active, to allow filterring
wsData.Select
With wsData.Range("AI2", wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "AI").End(xlUp))
    ' Column AI is col num 35
    .AutoFilter 35, "YES"
    .AutoFilter 37, "YES"
End With

wsData.Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy

wsDest.Select
Columns("B:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsData.Select
wsData.Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Copy

wsDest.Select
Columns("D:D").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

wsDest.Range("B1").Value = "ColumnB"
wsDest.Range("D1").Value = "ColumnD"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Shai Rado but it takes column C too it's a range, I m new in VBA so sorry for my questions, and the destination file begins in column B instead of A

Comment: @BKChedlia see edited answer code, you wanted to copy Column B and D to Column B and D without copying Column C, is it correct ?

Comment: Can we add another filter to this one for another column AK ?

Comment: yes, the question is how many after ? because then maybe this code and way of implementation will be very inefficient

Comment: I have to put 2 filters that's all

Comment: @BKChedlia then edit your post according to your second filter needed. If possible add an Edit 1: so everyone that reads this post understands the chnages as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117720/discussion-between-shai-rado-and-bkchedlia).